# C++ - Passing string value to a function using uint8_t pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, hadoop, impala

I am learning C++ in order to create a custom function (user defined function is how cloudera call it) that I want to use in Hadoop Cloudera Impala SQLs. Cloudera have provided a header file that has type definitions for custom function arguments

```
struct AnyVal {
  bool is_null;
  AnyVal(bool is_null = false) : is_null(is_null) {}
};
//Integer Value
struct IntVal : public AnyVal {
  int32_t val;

  IntVal(int32_t val = 0) : val(val) { }

  static IntVal null() {
    IntVal result;
    result.is_null = true;
    return result;
  }
}
//String Value
struct StringVal : public AnyVal {
  static const int MAX_LENGTH = (1 << 30);
  int len;
  uint8_t* ptr;
  /// Construct a StringVal from ptr/len. Note: this does not make a copy of ptr
  /// so the buffer must exist as long as this StringVal does.
  StringVal(uint8_t* ptr = NULL, int len = 0) : len(len), ptr(ptr) {
    assert(len >= 0);
  };
  /// Construct a StringVal from NULL-terminated c-string. Note: this does not make a copy of ptr so the underlying string must exist as long as this StringVal does.
  StringVal(const char* ptr) : len(strlen(ptr)), ptr((uint8_t*)ptr) {}

  static StringVal null() {
    StringVal sv;
    sv.is_null = true;
    return sv;
  }
}
```

Now for a simple Add function like the one below I understood how to pass the reference of IntVal object after setting IntVal.val and it worked !

```
IntVal AddUdf(FunctionContext* context, const IntVal& arg1, const IntVal& arg2) {
  if (arg1.is_null || arg2.is_null) return IntVal::null();
  return IntVal(arg1.val + arg2.val);
} 

int main() {
impala_udf::FunctionContext *FunctionContext_t ;
IntVal num1, num2 , res;
num1.val=10;
num2.val=20;
IntVal& num1_ref = num1;
IntVal& num2_ref = num2;
res = AddUdf(FunctionContext_t, num1_ref, num2_ref);
cout << "Addition Result = " << res.val << "\n";
}
```

But I don't know how to do similar thing for a string function as StringVal requires me to pass pointer of uint8_t type for a string? I tried below one but then received ***"error: cannot convert std::string* to uint8_t* in assignment"***

```
int main() {
impala_udf::FunctionContext *FunctionContext_t ;
StringVal str , res;
string input="Hello";
str.len=input.length();
str.ptr=&input;
StringVal& arg1=str;
res = StripVowels(FunctionContext_t, str);
cout << "Result = " << (char *) res.ptr<< "\n";
}
```

I also tried the following but no joy. Any *pointer* in the right direction will be much appreciated. Thanks.

```
str.ptr=reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(&input);
```

Comment: Supposing `string` is a `std::string`, you get a pointer to its internal data using `input.c_str()` (not `&input` which gets you a `string*`).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! For starters, using `reinterpret_cast` to pretend a `std:;string` is a character array isn't going to work. You should have a look at [`std::string::c_str()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str), which returns you a pointer to the character array managed by the `std::string`.

Comment: But the second problem will be that `c_str()` returns a `const` reference, while your `StringVal` class expects something non-`const`. So you may have to allocate and manage your own copy of the character array to pass into `StringVal`.

Comment: @mindriot thanks for the welcome and the words of wisdom :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String itself is not a character pointer (which is what you need), but you can get one by using the c_str function.

```
str.ptr=(uint8_t*)(input.c_str ());
```

If you want to use new-style casts you might need both a const_cast (to cast from const char * to char *) and a reinterpret_cast, depending on how str.ptr is defined.

Comment: A small suggestion here: 
```str.ptr = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(input.data())``` should also work. The only reason I'm suggesting this is to avoid the traditional c-style casting. Using the data method of a string, the const prefix is averted. So, you could simply do a reinterpret cast here to convert a char* to a uint8_t*

Answer (score 0):

That's because you need a pointer to c-string, and you provide a pointer to `std::string`. `str.ptr = input.c_str()` should work for you.

EDIT:
However, it seems you need a non-const pointer. In this case you need to allocate `input` variable yourself, like:

`char input[128];`

This creates a fixed size array on the stack.
But you might want to allocate it dynamically with new:
`char* input = new char[size];`

Also check out functions in the [cstring header](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/?kw=cstring), you might want to use those.

You might also need to cast it to `uint8_t*` as described above.

Don't forget to `delete[]` the string later when you don't need it anymore. But since you pass it to a function, this function should probably handle this.

Comment: Thanks. "You might also need to cast it to uint8_t* as described above" - I'm guessing by above you meant Guijt's post?

Comment: @AlwaysConfused Yes. But it might just happen automatically, I'm not sure.

Comment: @AlwaysConfused Also note that a comment in your code says: "the buffer must exist as long as this StringVal does." Which means you need to hold onto the char buffer you created. But you will need to `delete[]` it together with StringVal. I don't see anything in the header which deletes ptr for you.

Comment: Whether a const-cast is an acceptable solution depends on how the API uses the variable. Many APIs incorrectly ask for char * while they really only use const char *; in this case I have no problem with const-casting. Another thing to take into account is whether the string must persist after its use in the API. If not, again, I'd be fine with a const-cast rather than making a copy and giving yourself another resource to track...

Comment: @H.Guijt According to the comment I mentioned above: "Note: this does not make a copy of ptr so the buffer must exist as long as this StringVal does." So he does need to keep the buffer.

Comment: @AlwaysConfused Would be great if you upvoted my answer for the effort!

Comment: @Aikei I did, but a popup said vote will be visible only after I earn 15 rep :)